# How to change the parameter in pd.DateOffset in python code?

Tags: python, datetimeoffset

I have two different type of data. First data frame is in hourly and second data frame is in minutely. So, I need to forecast this data 24 hours & 30 minutes ahead respectively. But I have problem to make the function I created can work with both kind of data frame.

Let says, I want to subset my data set, into training data set and testing data set.

#### If my data in hours, I need to used function `hours`

```
def split_data(df, tend):       
    train=df[:index-pd.DateOffset(hours=1)]
    test=df[index:index+pd.DateOffset(hours=tend-1)]
```

#### If my data in minutes, I need to used function `minutes`

```
def split_data(df, tend):       
    train=df[:index-pd.DateOffset(minutes=1)]
    test=df[index:index+pd.DateOffset(minutes=tend-1)]
```

#### I already try by ignore the time function, but failed to split the data for minutely and hourly data

```
def split_data(df, tend):       
    train=df[:index-pd.DateOffset(1)]
    test=df[index:index+pd.DateOffset(tend-1)]
```

I expected the function can work both kind of data frame, I also try assign the function, yet failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use keyword arguments to pass multiple values like this:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:10:11')
ts
Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:10:11')

ts + pd.DateOffset(months=3)
Timestamp('2017-04-01 09:10:11')

ts + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
Timestamp('2017-01-04 09:10:11')

custom_args = {"days":1, "hours":3} # pass variable number of arguments
ts + pd.DateOffset(**custom_args)
Timestamp('2017-01-02 12:10:11')

custom_args = {"days":1, "hours":0}
ts + pd.DateOffset(**custom_args)
Timestamp('2017-01-02 09:10:11')

custom_args = {"days":1, "hours":0, "minutes":0}
ts + pd.DateOffset(**custom_args)
Timestamp('2017-01-02 09:10:11')
```

For your case you can try this way:

```
def split_data(df, tend, custom_args, unit="hours"): # or unit can be minutes  
    custom_args[unit] = 1
    train=df[:index-pd.DateOffset(**custom_args)]
    custom_args[unit] = tend - 1
    test=df[index:index+pd.DateOffset(**custom_args)]

custom_args = {"hours":0, "minutes":0, "minutes":0} # you can specify more arguments based on your requirements.
split_data(df, tend, custom_args, unit="hours")
```

To see what all arguments you can pass check out this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html

Comment: but for my case, i need two keyword argument for my dummy function. It is other ways instead of assign for each keyword? because in my real function, I need to defines 5 different keyword argument to forecast at different point.